# How do i subtract time from a datetime-local input?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm a newbie in JavaScript and have little to no experience in it. Clicking the button will print the input time.

What i was trying to do was subtract the time by 9 hours 30 minutes and I'm unable to find a way to do it.

It will help me a lot if someone could explain how to do this.

I've attached the whole HTML document below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("meeting-time").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time" name="meeting-time">
<button onclick="myFunction()">click to print time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make use of the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) Object.

1. Pass the input as a Date object
2. Set the new date by subtracting hours and minutes as necessary

Side Note: If you have more complex operations which include dates, you can make use of a third-party library like [Moments Js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("meeting-time").value;
  var date = new Date(x); // parse date as a Date object: TODO: Error handling -> sanitize the input
  date.setHours(date.getHours() - 9); // change the date object by subtracting hours from the same date object
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 30); // change the date object by subtracting minutes from the same date object
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time" name="meeting-time">
<button onclick="myFunction()">click to print time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hassle with the javascript-date-Object and its quirks, then you could use dayjs: https://day.js.org/

DayJS allows you to use Dates very easily in Javascript, e.g.:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
let now = dayjs();
console.log(now.format());
```

This is how you could subtract a specific unit of time from a date with dayjs:

```
dayjs().subtract(7, 'year')
```

Comment: if you like the answer, you're allowed to upvote :P
dayjs is known for it's ultrasmall bundle size :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following libraries to achieve your requirement,

- moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)
- Luxon(https://moment.github.io/luxon/)
- date-fns (https://date-fns.org/)
- Day.js (https://day.js.org/)

Example for date-fns :

```
var sub = require('date-fns/sub');
   
// Subtract the following duration from 15 June 2017 15:29:20
const result = sub(new Date(2017, 5, 15, 15, 29, 20), {
  years: 2,
  months: 9,
  weeks: 1,
  days: 7,
  hours: 5,
  minutes: 9,
  seconds: 30
})
//=> Mon Sep 1 2014 10:19:50
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Thank you for submitting the answer. This would indeed be helpful for me when i have to work with date and time